# How to show or hide a post based on meta_value selection?

Tags: publish, meta-value, draft

How would I go about hiding a post based on a meta_value selection done on the back end.

The usual method is to just change the post status from Publish to Draft however, I want this to work based on a dropdown selection.

meta_key being `current_status` and a dropdown box with meta_value of `active` and `leased`.

If `active` is selected the post is shown, and `leased` would hide the post.

Any ideas on how to do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to alter the main query with [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) arguments to only select posts with `active` `current_status`.

This example would work for your main posts page. See [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for how to determine when other types of queries are run.

```
function wpa_current_status( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'current_status',
                'value' => 'active',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_current_status' );
```

EDIT- or within a custom query, set `meta_query` arguments directly:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'current_status',
            'value' => 'active',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$properties = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with posts made through a custom page. It still shows the posts even with `is_page`. To add some more information, these posts are going within a `function property_listing()` and I'm adding individual property's and selecting whether they are active or leased via `current_status`.

Comment: if you are creating a custom query via `WP_Query` and not altering the main query, then just add the `meta_query` parameters directly to your query.

Comment: I -almost- have this working. I decided to alter main query as the results are all over the site and not just specific pages. In order to see what areas it's working on, I used `if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {`. It works in the backend where I can see and edit posts as it will filter to only show those with `active` status, but in the front end it returns 404 errors with nothing found and unable to filter. Thank you by the way for helping me with this.

Comment: it's not going to work on the main query of a single page, it has to be an archive of some sort- the main posts page, a category, a custom post type archive, etc., or otherwise you need to create an additional query.

Comment: I tried using `if ( $query->is_page( 'search-results' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {` so that it uses a specific page for the results, and the same occurs. Nothing shows. I'm going to have to do some digging as I'm thinking the `current_status` value isn't properly being linked to posts. Not sure what else would cause it to not give a return.

Comment: **Update** It was indeed `current_status` not properly linked to the specific search results. It's working now that I adjusted the code for the results. Thanks for all the help Milo.

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop, extract the value.

Once you have it, do a simple `if` test to see if it's leased. If it is, you just do a `continue` via PHP.